# Angular: How to get object behind *ngFor DOM element without an event?

Tags: angular, angular-ngfor

How do I access the object behind a dom element based by the id of the dom element or something else that does not involve an event?

for example I have:

```
arr1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:5, b:10}, {a:20, b:50}];

<li *ngFor="let obj of arr1; let indexObj=index" id="{{indexObj}}">
    {{obj.a}}
</li>

document.getElementById("1");
```

But I want to be able to acces the properties a and b associated with the li DOM element

Edit: question was not clear enough so I'll try to expand. what you normally would do

```
<li *ngFor="let obj of arr1; let indexObj=index" id="{{indexObj}}" (click)="somefunc(obj)">
        {{obj.a}}
 </li>
```

and then I can acces obj in my function

```
somefunc(obj) {
    console.log(obj.a);
}
```

I want to achieve what i'm doing in `somefunc` without the click event or any other event. so for example I can acces the DOM element li by `document.getElementById("1");` or by `this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#1')` but I want to have access to the obj associated with the DOM element so I want to be able to do something like this.

```
somefunc2() {
    let el = document.getElementById("1");
    console.log(obj.a associated with el);
}
```

Comment: Your question isnt pretty clear? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it's more clear now

Comment: Are you looking for something like a view child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the id, then use the array `find` in your data source.

```
   const trgItem = arr1.find(item => return item.a === 1);
```

You should also change your html this way to setup the id properly:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let obj of arr1; let indexObj=index" id="{{indexObj}}">
        {{obj.a}}
    </li>
<ul>
```

If you know the index,  use the `indexOf(0)` function of the array.

If you want to get it when something happens,  then you can only do that with an event.

Comment: Hmm this would indeed work if I add a attribute id to my li element and list of objects. Still there should be an easier/nicer way I hope. If not I will use this and accepts this answer

Comment: Bear in mind, that this would also work with the getElementById(0), now that we interpolated the indexObj. Without the id, you can just use the `arr1.indexOf(0)` to get the respective object, as the index is just 0,1,2,..

Comment: That's a bit of a nicer way to do it thanks for the effort! I just want to see if there is an "Angular" way of doing it, if not I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not working because you are not interpolating the id...**

Your html should be:

```
<li *ngFor="let obj of arr1; index as indexObj" id="{{indexObj}}">
  {{obj.a}} //also you had a typo here (ibj instead of obj)
</li>
```

**EDIT FOR THE UPDATED QUESTION:**

Since you know the id, to retrieve the item in array you can do this:

```js
const arr1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:5, b:10}, {a:20, b:50}];


const id = 1;
const item = arr1[id];
console.log(item, item.a, item.b);
```

Comment: Quite true! Depending on what the OP is trying to achieve this could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks but that was just a typo. I updated my answer to expand on what I want to achieve

Comment: @user3261212 please take a look at the update answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjo4xl) working example for your use, modify your component code like this-

```
 arr1 = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 5, b: 10 }, { a: 20, b: 50 }];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const val = Number(document.getElementById('1').innerHTML);
    console.log(this.arr1.find(ele => ele.a === val)); // you'll get the object here.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive to get the object of an element or getting all children by using `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren`

@ViewChildren:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <alert></alert>
    <alert type="danger"></alert>
    <alert type="info"></alert>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren(AlertComponent) alerts: QueryList<AlertComponent>

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Here you get all instances of the alert component
    this.alerts.forEach(alertInstance => console.log(alertInstance));
  }
}
```

For more information about that: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren